# Is the data system for ATM-machines using eventual consistency?

Tags: architecture, banking, distributed-system, acid, eventual-consistency

I wounder how the world-wide [ATM-systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_teller_machine) are architected. It must be pretty hard for the banks to design a consistent system world wide. Do they use eventual consistency for this or do they use a great ACID system?

I can be in Sweden one day, where my bank is and use the ATM, then take the airplane to USA or Thailand and use the ATM abroad a few hours later. If the system is consistent, then they need a very reliable connection to anywhere in the world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The systems are all different. Many are based on PCs (when one crashes, you can see [BIOS messages](http://www.flickr.com/photos/shadowfoot/3991087984/) on the screen). Some run [Windows](http://simonmoneyonline.com/?p=77) or [Linux](http://zee-nix.blogspot.com/2008/03/linuxgtk-based-atm.html) (couldn't find a crash image for those ... hmmm...).

What happens is that your credit card is the common key. All those systems can read it and check that it's valid. Then, they give you some of their money.

Eventually, the system will collect all that data and send it to the company which issued the card. This can be on- or offline. The accounts will be updated and after some time, the company will reimburse the bank.

Comment: So I can take out $100 even if I only have $80 on my bank account, when I am abroad?

Comment: Yes. It's a *credit* card, after all. The issuer of the card will then get the money back from you.

Comment: Ah, you have a point there. However, I don't have any credit on my Visa-card so it's a *debit card*.

Comment: Well, they are called credit cards even though it's only a "credit" for a few days (the time between you used the card and they debit your bank account).

Answer (score 2):

When you withdraw from an ATM, the transaction is eventually approved by your own bank (called **issuer**) no matter which ATM you use. The financial institution which owns the ATM is called **acquirer**. Between the issuer and the acquirer, there can be one ore more interechange gateways like Mastercard or Visa or others.

The interchange gateways can be local if the transaction is being routed within a single country (e.g., both issuer and acquirer are in Sweden). It could also involve an interchange gateway if they are both in different countries.

Almost similar system is used when a transaction happens over the Internet.

On a side note, you might be interested in the [development environments available for ATMs](http://www.thejaywalker.net/2006/08/development-environments-for-atms.html).